# UnsupportedClassVersionError occurs during execution jar

Tags: jar, compiler-errors

I have tried to package my project into jar by using default spring boot plugin. That is my build tag looks like - simple as is.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As expected, I receive in target folder my .jar (executing mvn install). But, when I tring to execute jar using

```
java -jar <filename>.jar
```

The problem araise, here is stacktrace

```
> C:\Users\Misha\IdeaProjects\discoveery-service\target>java -jar discoveery-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/example/discoveeryservice/DiscoveryServiceApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)

W
```

hat is that? I do not meet this problem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it - only thing I change is the version of java maven will package from 11 to 8

```
<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
</properties>
```